# Probability of specific value of the difference between the number of heads and the number of tails when a coin is tossed several times

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ represent the difference between the number of heads and the number of tails when a coin is tossed $41$ times. What is $P(X=5)$?

The first answer I got was $31/41$. However, that is wrong. I did $41-2\cdot 5 = 31/41$.

Comment: Let $Y$ be the number of heads. Then $41-Y$ is the number of tails. I will interpret the question as asking for the probability that $Y-(41-Y)=5$, that is, the probability that $Y=23$. This probability is $\binom{41}{23}\cdot \frac{1}{2^{41}}$. But perhaps they mean that the *absolute value* of the difference is $5$, in which case we need to multiply by $2$.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3):

Let $H$ be the number of heads and $T$ be the number of tails. You want $P(|H-T|=5)$. We have $T= 41-H$. So \begin{align}P(|H-T|=5) &= P(|H-41+H|=5) \\&= P(|2H-41|=5) \\&= P(2H-41 = 5 \text{ or } 2H-41 = -5) \\&= P(H=23 \text{ or } H=18) \\&= \binom{41}{23}(1/2)^{41} + \binom{41}{18}(1/2)^{41} \\&= \binom{41}{18}(1/2)^{40}\end{align} since $\binom{41}{18} = \binom{41}{23}$.